# Legend for OpenTopoMap in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, legend, opentopomap

I want to use [OpenTopoMap](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/#filter=OpenTopoMap) as background map in Leaflet.

I can't find information about the colour encoding of heights to create a legend.

Does anyone know the correspondence between colours and height intervals?